# Do I need a transit visa if I have a layover in Narita, and I am transferring from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1 and changing airlines?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, filipino-citizens, nrt

This is my first time flying internationally. I have a Philippine passport and I am booking separate roundtrip tickets from Manila to Narita with Philippine Airlines and from Narita to San Lucas (Cabo), Mexico with Aeromexico Airways. The Philippine Airlines flight from Manila will arrive at Terminal 2 and the Aeromexico flight will depart from Terminal 1.

I wanted to make sure I won't be held up by Immigration, so should I get a transit visa for a 3 to 4 hour layover in Narita Airport, transferring from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a transit visa, not because you're changing terminals (you don't need it for that) but because 1. you need to collect your luggage and 2. At the departure airport the staff will consider Tokyo your destination because your other ticket is separate.

If you were transiting overnight, you could enter for up to 72 hours without a visa:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets transiting
>   to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a
>   max. stay of 72 hours **only if there are no connecting flights
>   on the same calendar day**

However, seeing as it's a same-day connection, you **do** need a transit visa.